# Custom java word count mapreduce program using hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

New to Hadoop! I'm trying to modify the code of wordcount program to only output words that start with "a", for example.

I've modified the mapper method code, but for unknown reasons it stills outputs all the words in the input file. The rest of the code is unchanged and can be found at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hadoop/hdinsight-use-mapreduce.

```java
public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context
                    ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        Text word = new Text();
        StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
        while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
            String currentWord = itr.nextToken();
            if(currentWord.startsWith("a")) {
                word.set(currentWord);
                context.write(word, new IntWritable(1));
            }
        }
}
```

The output file still contains all the words. I was only expecting words starting with letter - a.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How does your output file look like? What are the counts for the words that do not start with "a". Add some debug statements and make sure your code changes are indeed being run on the cluster.

Comment: Hi @Amit , thanks for commenting. Well, the output file is pretty standard following the "[key]\t[value]" format where _key_ is word and _value_ is word count.  The counts for all words are correct, but I'm only interested in words starting with "a". Also, I'd like to add that I've to run this program in Azure Hadoop cluster so I'm not sure how exactly it can be debugged.

Comment: This method itself looks fine. You're going to have to debug further by looking at logs.

Comment: Also are you sure you're running this mapper, and not the default one you linked to?